# MySQL syntax Error 1064 Extra column

Tags: mysql, database, attributes, entity, erd

```
create table student(
    SID char(10),
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    Units char(10),
    constraint primary key(Sid)
)engine=innodb;
```

this is correct but i need a anther column call Level

```
create table student(
    SID char(10),
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    Units char(10),
    class level char(10),
    constraint primary key(Sid)
)engine=innodb;
```

i can't run this

i don't know why 
please explain

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have space between `class level`

Try  change the space with _

```
 create table student(
   SID char(10),
   Name varchar(100) not null,
   Units char(10),
   class_level char(10),
   constraint primary key(Sid)
)engine=innodb;
```

or use backticks

```
 create table student(
   SID char(10),
   Name varchar(100) not null,
   Units char(10),
   `class level` char(10),
   constraint primary key(Sid)
)engine=innodb;
```